# Packages not installing, class does not exist error, Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The package is an email registration functionality. Here is my composer.json file

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^3.1",
    "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "^2.0"
},
```

The trouble package is the user-verification one at the bottom.

Here are my providers in app.php

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider::class,
    Jrean\UserVerification\UserVerificationServiceProvider::class,
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],
```

The package is at the bottom of the first block, before the service providers.

And here are my aliases from the same file.

```
 'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'UserVerification' => Jrean\UserVerification\Facades\UserVerification::class

],
```

I get a complaint in command line that the class is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your Eloquent-Slugabble class.

You have this your providers list:

```
Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider::class,
```

But according to the package documentation, you should have this:

```
Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\ServiceProvider::class,
```

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Just get this corrected and run composer again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment this line out:

```
Jrean\UserVerification\UserVerificationServiceProvider::class,
```

Then run `composer update`, then bring the line back in

You should add your service provider to the config only after it's been installed already. You could also try `composer update --no-scripts` so that Laravel post-install scripts are not run.

Answer (score 0):

comment service providers and aliases then run the `composer update` command in the CLI (command line interface)